# Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected when converting NSAttributedString to html

Tags: html, nsattributedstring

I'm getting a warning in the debugger in XCode: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected when converting an NSAttributedString to html data. Not sure what is causing this or how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
let testString = NSAttributedString(string: "test")
    let documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
    let htmlData = try? testString.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
```

The data does get created, but not sure why I'm getting the warning.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out what was causing this. It seems that the string to data function wants some idea of what text encoding to use. Here is the fixed code which removes the debugger warning:

```
let testString = NSAttributedString(string: "test")
    let documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]
    let htmlData = try? testString.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
```